# Prevent adding duplicate item to a NSMutableOrderedSet

Tags: swift, nsmutableorderedset

Add new array (`addObjectFromArray`) to  `NSMutableOrederedSet`, how to check if the `NSMutableOrederset` already has an existing copy of item/items and no duplication happens?

Code :

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, jsonUrl).responseJSON(){
                (_, _, JSON, _) in

    if JSON != nil {

                let imageInfos = (JSON!.valueForKey("image") as [NSDictionary]).map {
                    ImageInfo(id: $0["id"] as String, url: $0["url"] as String)
                }
                self.tableData.addObjectsFromArray(imageInfos)
```

---

Same for both viewDidLoad() and handlePullToRefresh()

- jsonUrl is different for the two methods

Comment: NSMutable(Ordered)Set is a collection of *distinct* items. You cannot add duplicate objects. The addition of an object which is already contained in the set is simply ignored.

Comment: here is my situation, in viewDidLoad -> JsonImage -> array containing id an url of image.
when pull to refresh -> new set of jsonImage -> array containing only ids and url of new image and adding it to the existing NSMutableOrderedSet.
Every time i pull to refresh the new images gets duplicated

Comment: Could you please provide the code. What objects do store in the NSMutableOrederedSet ? the object must implement isEqual method correctly

Comment: Check your implementation of `isEqual` and `hash`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feed back, i did not implement isEqual and hash method and that was the problem.